# Where to see exact pixel size of objects in a scene?

Tags: godot

I am currently editing objects in the main scene of my demo game. However, it is frustrating for me to be unable to see the exact width/height of a selected object.

Is there any way to see these desired properties? Or do I have to go through each scene and compute the various applied scales/transforms myself in order to determine this information?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not every node has a size (your player's root node for example). In your specific case, you'll want to look at the children inside of your player.

On a CollisionShape2D, click on the Shape itself to reveal size information.

[image: as seen here.]

A Sprite node will only display the source texture's size if you click on it.

You can still get accurate size info by enabling Region and setting the Rect manually. You will probably want Auto Slice. This is done at the bottom of the screen in a TextureRegion widget. Just make sure to set scale back to 1x1 when you're finished defining it.

[image]

Comment: This seems like an awfully basic feature that is missing from the editor. Do you know how to get in touch with the devs?

Comment: As for your comment *"Not every node has a size"*, then simply show N/A on certain nodes - this is exactly how the popular Sketch mobile design app works.

Comment: You can reach the devs through any of the outlets listed here. https://godotengine.org/community

Comment: I think it would be a nice addition to certain nodes, but it doesn’t make sense for most of them. “YSort” just sorts its children by their vertical position on the screen. It has no concept of size. Likewise for the basic “Node”.

Comment: It's not about *making sense*. This is an editor mean't to simplify development and reduce programmer strain. The fact that you can't take one single look at the screenshot I posted and tell me what the exact size my character is on the screen – but instead have to type out an entire lengthy post on how to find such information means that the program has failed in that aspect.